# Problems with Postgresql Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a problem when running:

```
rake db:create:all
```

I currently have:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.0

$ which psql
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql
```

And get:

```
$ rake db:create:all
could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/Users/stephanecedroni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
.....
.....
```

Tried to uninstall and re-install `pg` gem but still would not work.

First tried to follow Ryan Bates screencast but had some problems, and then checked the Heroku Postgres suggesting to set this path:

`PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: I used to have a similar problem.  How did you install Postgresql?  What does your database.yml look like?

Comment: thx for your reply. Downloaded on Postgres website. Tried to install it with homebrew following RyanBates screencast.. and using the same database.yml 
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:

Answer (score 2):

It could be that rake is trying  to connect to `/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432` but the domain socket is actually somewhere else.  Mine is at `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`.  You can try these:

Specify `host: localhost` in your database.yml.  For example:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  # other stuff
```

OR

Create a symlink in `/var/pgsql_socket/` to where `.s.PGSQL.5432` actually lives.

```
mkdir /var/pgsql_socket
ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

You'll probably have to chown and chmod the links too.  I'm not sure if you have to link the .s.PGSQL.5432.lock as well.

The first option is a lot easier.  Not sure if one or the other is better.

Comment: You must be right, when I run postgres and check \conninfo in the psql console I get:
You are connected to database "stephanecedroni" as user "stephanecedroni" via socket in "/tmp" at port "5432"
How would you change the domain socket like yours? Not sure how to create a symlink actually..Thx for your help

Comment: Try the ```host: localhost``` option first, that's much easier.  Post back if you need more help.